# Python Selenium opening random empy webdrivers when I run my code, how do I stop this?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
import random

url = "https://www.youtube.com/"

list_of_drivers = [webdriver.Firefox(), webdriver.Chrome(), webdriver.Edge()]

Driver = random.choice(list_of_drivers)

Driver.get(url)
```

I'm trying to cycle though a list of random webdrivers using selenium.

It does a good job at picking a random webdriver and opening the URL however, it also opens up other webdrivers with a blanck page.

How do I stop this from happening?

I am running python 2.7 in a virtualenv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list_of_drivers = [webdriver.Firefox(), webdriver.Chrome(), webdriver.Edge()]`

You created three instances already in this line, that's why all 3 browsers show up with a blank page at the very beginning.

```
Driver = random.choice(list_of_drivers)
Driver.get(url)
```

And then you randomly choose one to open a webpage, leaving the rest doing nothing.

**Instead of creating three instances, just create one:**

```
list_of_drivers = ['Firefox', 'Chrome', 'Edge']
Driver = getattr(webdriver, random.choice(list_of_drivers))()
Driver.get(url)
```